# Xcode instruments generated lots of __CFCachedURLResponse memory leak

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have not used any `NSURL` API in my code  but Xcode Instruments said my code has a lot of `__CFCachedURLResponse` memory leaks.

For instance,

```
Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame
__CFCachedURLResponse,10 < multiple > 320 Bytes IPhoneUIBase    
-[InterestGroupStockTR_RTS composeRTSData:]
```

The code is that after creating adding couple of objects to array, then call custom class.

```
NSMutableArray *arrCodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for(int j = 0; j < countCode; j++ )
{
    NSDictionary *pData = [listData objectAtIndex:j];       
    NSString *stockCode = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pData ];
            NSMutableDictionary *codeData2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:stockCode , @"acCode" , NULL ];
    [arrCodes addObject:codeData2];
    [codeData2 release];
}   
[trData.dict setObject:arrCodes forKey:@"MULTI_SBR_ARRAYRP"];               
[self requestWithData:trData];
    [arrCodes removeAllObjects];
[arrCodes release];
```

- Another question is  Whats the difference between `__CFCachedURLResponse` and `__CFURLCacheNode`?. Some of classes have `__CFURLCacheNode` memory leak according  to instrument.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are attached to the specific process of the app not just attached to the device?

Comment: Are you calling `[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:]` anywhere in your code ? You should - to set up the shard cache for responses - but you must only do this once in your app (preferably in the app delegate after the app launches). If you call this method more than once in your app, in my experience you will start to see exactly this kind of memory leak.